# Is it possible to git auto push after commit, but only up to HEAD~2, so that remote is always 2 commits behind local

Tags: git

I always fear losing my un-pushed work in case of computer or disk failure.

I can set up a post-commit script to auto push on every commit, but I "undo last commit" way too often, usually several times a day. Sometimes I undo HEAD~1 too.

So, I hope to auto push after each commit, but always keep remote branch 2 commits behind. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just auto push HEAD with force? Then the "undo" won't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a post-commit hook (which will run automatically after every successful commit) that calls `git push origin HEAD~2:$(git branch --show-current)` (which will push two commits behind `HEAD` on the current branch to the `origin` remote).

(edited command, thanks @phd)